# Can't use string ("0") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl, catalyst

My Code is:

```
my $mortgageValue = $c->forward('/_asset/_real_estate/_mortgage/browse/vw_asset_real_estate_mortgage', ["data", "getRowHash", "*", "asset_real_estate_id='".$realEstateId."' AND active='1'", "", "1"]);
if (@{$mortgageValue}) { # is the line that shows the error
        $amortizationPeriodDetails = $mortgageValue->{amortization_period}||"";
}
```

I think the query returns null as there is no value for the condition, but how can I check that?

Comment: wait a minute; on your second line, $mortgageValue is an arrayref and on the next line it's a hashref; which is it really?

Comment: Without `strict refs` symbolic references are still legal.  In this case you would be overwriting `$0` which **should** contain your program name.  Let this serve as one more reason that symbolic references are an excellent source of hard to track down bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, the forward method would return undef instead; a method that returns 0 sometimes and an arrayref sometimes is harder to work with.  But failing that, you can do:

```
if ( @{ $mortgageValue || [] } ) {
```

or

```
if ( $mortgageValue && @$mortgageValue ) {
```

Comment: You'd have to use those even if `forward` returned undef.

Answer (score 0):

`$mortgageValue` is not an array-reference. So you can not dereference it. Looks like `$mortgageValue` is a scalar.